# AWS Java SDK v2: Upload a directory to S3

Tags: kotlin, amazon-s3, file-upload, aws-java-sdk-2.x, directory-upload

I would like to upload a directory to S3 using the AWS Java SDK v2.

For example, how would I implement the following function?

```
fun uploadDirectory(bucket: String, prefix: String, directory: Path)
```

I would like the contents of `directory` to be replicated at `s3://bucket/prefix/` on S3.

The v2 SDK documentation has an example for [uploading a single object](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/examples-s3-objects.html#upload-object), but there doesn't seem to be an equivalent to this [Upload a Directory](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/examples-s3-transfermanager.html#transfermanager-upload-directory) example from v1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement it by using the following strategy:

1. Use [`Files.walk`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#walk(java.nio.file.Path,java.nio.file.FileVisitOption...)) to walk the directory, identifying all of the files.
2. Asynchronously upload the files using the SDK, via [`S3AsyncClient.putObject`](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/services/s3/S3AsyncClient.html#putObject-software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.PutObjectRequest-java.nio.file.Path-).
3. Use [`CompletableFuture.allOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#allOf(java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture...)) to combine all of the upload tasks, and wait for completion.

This strategy uses the async client's [default thread pool](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/asynchronous.html#advanced-operations) of 50 threads. This is working fine for me with directories that contain thousands of files.

The `s3Prefix` here is the prefix to add to each object uploaded to the bucket, equivalent to the target directory.

```
fun uploadDirectory(s3Bucket: String, s3Prefix: String, directory: Path) {
    require(directory.isDirectory())

    Files.walk(directory).use { stream ->
        stream.asSequence()
            .filter { it.isRegularFile() }
            .map { path ->
                putObject(
                    s3Bucket = s3Bucket,
                    s3Key = "$s3Prefix/${directory.relativize(path)}",
                    path = path
                )
            }
            .toList().toTypedArray()
    }.let { CompletableFuture.allOf(*it) }.join()
}

private fun putObject(s3Bucket: String, s3Key: String, path: Path)
    : CompletableFuture<PutObjectResponse> {
    val request = PutObjectRequest.builder()
        .bucket(s3Bucket)
        .key(s3Key)
        .build()

    return s3AsyncClient.putObject(request, path)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`TransferManager` along with some other high level libraries is not yet available in v2. so you will have to use v1 instead, from the [migration guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/migration-whats-different.html)

> High-level libraries, such as the Amazon S3 Transfer Manager and the
> Amazon SQS Client-side Buffering, are not yet available in version
> 2.x. See the AWS SDK for Java 2.x changelog for a complete list of libraries.
>
> If your application depends on these libraries, see Using both SDKs
> side-by-side to learn how to configure your pom.xml to use both 1.x
> and 2.x. Refer to the AWS SDK for Java 2.x changelog for updates about
> these libraries.

Comment: There is a [preview](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/transfer-manager.html) of the transfer manager available, but it doesn't support uploading a directory yet. However, it's possible to do it without the transfer manager using asynchronous uploads, see my answer.

Comment: @AdamMillerchip ofcourse its possible to iterate over the directory and put objects individually, but you were asking about a solution similar to the `TransferManager`, which as I stated is not yet available.

Comment: I asked how to write a function that uploads a directory to S3 using the AWS SDK v2, I didn't ask for a specific method.

Comment: ok, so you knew about how to upload a single object using s3 v2, but you didn't know how to iterate over a directory. if that was the case then certainly you have learned a new thing about java sdk. I am happy for you